# Visualworks mcz packages import with Monticello

Tags: smalltalk, visualworks, monticello

I'm trying to program a client for multitouch gestures using TUIO under SmallTalk/Visualworks.
In order to get the mcz package for TUIO, I'm using Monticello.

The problem is that whenever i try to load a package with Monticello, i always end receiving this error message :

[image]

I can show you the Stack if anyone is inerested in it.

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mcz package is essentially a compressed zip file. The current implementation of Monticello in VisualWorks uses external shell programs to uncompress and compress the source code to a Monticello mcz file.

When porting packages from Monticello to VisualWorks under Windows, there is usually a problem finding the corresponding zip.exe/unzip.exe. To solve your problem, try to set your PATH variable to your zip.exe/unzip.exe.

Another approach is to download the Info-ZIP package from the web. Place it into a subfolder in the image directory and change the execution logic of the VisualWorks Monticello Package. Browse for senders of shOne: in the VisualWorks Monticello Package and change the call.

The next thing to keep in mind when porting packages from Squeak or Pharo is to always define a Namespace which is named extactly after the first word of the monticello package name (upTo: $-). Define the namespace before loading the package.

i.e. `JQueryMobile-Libraries-NickAger.10.mcz -> Define a Namespace JQueryMobile`

Don't forget to import necessary Namespaces that the imported code requires to resolve the superclass names.

i.e. `JQueryMobile needs Seaside.*, Javascript.*, JQuery.*, Grease.*, Smalltalk.*`

Comment: Simple, precise, elegant ! Thanx, i was doubting the senders of shOne. This resolved the problem.